What can we learn from the local device density of states?
Many papers on quantum transport show results on local device density of states.
What can we learn by inspecting local device density of states?

More information will be added in the future
Band bending
interfacial states
As shown in the picture below from the reference  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevB.90.125441}

